# How can I  create Content Slider in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to create a gallery in wordpress to show the latest **3 posts**. The gallery will show the image of the post with the title of the post and part of the post (the paragraph that is before --more-- tag in wordpress). I need it to be dynamic just when I add a new post the gallery shows that.

well I did the following code

```
<div class="blogsgallery">

        <?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <p>
        <h3>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" 
rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h3>
        </p>

        <div class="entry-content">

            <div id="post-thumbnail">
              //the size of thumbnail 150X150 px  
              <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150)); ?> 
            </div>

//The code will show only the text before the "Read More ..." tag !
                <?php 
                global $more;
                $more = 0;
                the_content("Read More ...");
                ?>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
```

This a loop to show the latest 3 posts. I need to make it a slider container. after a specific time, i.e 1 minute, slide 1 move to the left and show slide 2, etc ...

Please see the photo for more information:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change the amount of posts that show up through your settings. I suppose that is not a good solution for you; here is another way to do this:

You will need to edit a page in your theme. You may edit the main page; I'd recommend you [make a new page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) and use that as your front page.

Then you create a variation of [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Creating the loop with 3 posts (per page) would be done like this:

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=3' );
```

See more info in [the Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/); in particular, the [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) page.

Comment: links: [query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) [template_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags)  [creating a page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)

Comment: if it's pure html; create it as a static file; after this you'll have to see how your loop fits in.

Comment: Brtrnd how can I make it as a slide ? what should I add to make like a slide with two arrows for right and left sliding....

Answer (score 0):

Btrnd is technically correct about this. However, you don't seem to understand how Wordpress templates work. (I don't mean to be offensive). Maybe you're looking for a plugin to do it for you?

http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/30/top-10-content-slider-plugins-for-wordpress/

You could try anything in the above post. To install a plugin, download it and put it in your plugin directory. Alternatively, you can search for plugins directly from Wordpress and install them from the Wordpress back-end. See the codex (link below) for how to do this.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Installing_Plugins

Comment: it's ok no problem at all. I need to make it from scratch and need to be dynamic, just when i insert a new post, it shows that post immediately.